# Add claims in Microsoft Identity WebApp Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am trying to follow azure-samples specifically to sign-in users from my asp.net core 3.1 mvc app. The sample is available and documented [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg).

However, I couldn't find a way to add/modify claims I received in the token. The extension method used is `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication()` from `Microsoft.Identity.Web` nuget package version `0.4.0-preview`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new role claim is to the [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/claims/) with the following code:

```
public ActionResult AddClaim()
{
    Claim displayName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().NameClaimType);
    ViewBag.DisplayName = displayName != null ? displayName.Value : string.Empty;

    //ClaimType, Value, ValueType, Issuer
    Claim localClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Webpage, "http://localhost", ClaimValueTypes.String, "AADGuide");
    
    //Method 1 - short version
    ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().AddClaim(localClaim);
    
    //Method 2 - slightly longer version
    //var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    //var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    //identity.AddClaim(localClaim);    
    
    return View();
}
```

Also, you could add claims to Identity using [`IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-claims-to-identity-using-iuserclaimsprincipalfactory).

Comment: where you want me to add this code and call it from? This is what I have in Startup.cs class `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAD");`

Comment: As the article said,  `putting the claims in ClaimsPrincipal.Current`. So, you can  use `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().AddClaim(localClaim);` in startup.cs file to add claim.

Comment: Sorry, for being so ignorant but I'm not following you. Here is what I have in Startup.cs: 


`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
  services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAD")
  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
  .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("MSGraphApi"))
  .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
}


services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>{options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
 {
    // how to call call Graph to get AD groups and store them as claims?
 }}`

Comment: I implemented it as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/421). Thanks!